# Making a custom Distribution of Random Numbers

Tags: c++11, random

I am trying to make sense of the different distribution objects in c++11 and I am finding it overwhelming. I hope some of you can and will help.

---

This is why I am looking into all this:

I need a random number generator that I can adjust every time it is used so that it is more likely to produce the same number again. The second requirement I need to fill is that I need the random numbers generated to only be these numbers:
`{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 128}`

Third and last requirement is that on certain occasions I need to skip one or more numbers from the above set.

My problem is that I don't understand the descriptions of various distribution objects. I, thus, cannot determine what tools I need to use to meet my above needs.

Can somebody tell me what tools I need and how I need to use them? The more clear, concise and detailed the response the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range can be generated with a random number j in the range [0, 7], then you compute:

```
1 << j
```

to get your number.  `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` would be handy for generating the value in [0, 7].

Additionally you could use a `std::bernoulli_distribution` (which returns a random bool) to decide if the next number is going to be the same as the last one, or if you should generate a new number.  The `std::bernoulli_distribution` defaults to a 50/50 chance of true/false, but you can customize that distribution in the `bernoulli_distribution` constructor to anything you like (e.g. 80/20 or whatever).

If this isn't clear enough, just jump in with some code.  Try coding it up, and if it isn't working, post what you have, and I'm sure somebody will help.

Oh, forgot about your 3rd requirement:  For that just put your [0, 7] generation in a loop, and if you come up with a number you're supposed to skip, then iterate the loop, else break out of it.

Comment: Should I take your answer to mean there isn't a way to use these new c++11 objects/templates to specify particular numbers? Also thank you for the answer!

Comment: The uniform_int_distribution allows you to specify a low and high and generates ints in the range [low, high].  Most of the other distributions return floating point results with various probability distributions.

Answer (score 1):

For skipping numbers I completely agree with Howard that manual checking is probably the way to go, but there might be a better way altering the probability of a given number being generated.
Another way to do this would be to use a discrete_distribution object, which allows you to specify the probability of generating any given value, so for your example it would be something like

```
std::default_random_engine entropy;
std::array<double, 128> probs;
probs.fill(1.0);
std::discrete_distribution<int> choose(probs.begin(), probs.end());
```

then when you're in your loop, in addition to deciding whether or not to skip, you can increment one of those values by some amount to increase the odds of it coming up again, making sure to reinitialize the discrete distribution, like this:

```
int x;
double myValue = 0.2;//or whatever increment you want
for (something; something else; something else else)
{
  x = choose(entropy);
  if (skip(x))
    continue;//alternately you could set probs.at(x) = 0
  //only if you never want to generate it again
  probs.at(x) += myValue;
  choose = std::discrete_distribution<int>(probs.begin(), probs.end());
  output(x);
}
```

where skip and output are your functions to decide if x should be skipped and do whatever you want with the generated value respectively

Comment: I've done something similar to what you've suggested recently; but without mid algorithm reinitialization of the distribution object. I've wondered since experiencing unexpected behaviour with a std::bernoulli_distrib whether reinitializing the object might skew the accumulative statistics I might expect based on the statistics I can expect from the object over the course of an initialization. Does initializing, like you've suggested, alleviate that concern I have?

Comment: The only reason I reinitialize is that the discrete distribution gets built based on the array passed at initialization, so if you change that array (which in the example I gave we do) and want the distribution to reflect those changes you need to reinitialize (unless there's a more elegant way that I'm missing). For a bernoulli distribution unless you're changing the double you pass in at initialization reinitializing should not do anything to the overall statistics. My guess is that if you're experiencing unexpected behavior with a bernoulli distribution that it is a separate issue.

Comment: Well the only similarity that I know of is the reinitialization of the object. Obviously they are different objects and will behave differently but the initialization is what I am suspicious of. I should do some testing some time but I just don't find the time. Until I've squashed any concerns, about reinitialization causing an accumulative skewing of the data, I will be more comfortable with the dual object solution to regenerating the same number as the last generation had.